# How to add values to a dictionary while inside of a function (with Firebase)

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I declared a dictionary outside in a class file like so:

`var myDict: [Int: String] = [:]`

I also made a function to change the values inside a dictionary:

```
func firebaseToDictionary() {
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let infoRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("info")

    infoRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: String]
        for item in postDict! {

            let theString = item.value["FirebaseString"]
            let theNumber = item.value["FirebaseInt"]                

            self.myDict[theNumber] = theString

            //First Print
            print(myDict)
        }
    })
    //Second Print
    print(myDict)
}
```

At the `//First Print` the dictionary contains the new values and looks fine, but `//Second Print` shows the dictionary as it was created; as `[:]`. The `//Second Print` actually shows up in the terminal before `//First Print`

Why is my dictionary still showing up as [:] even after I changed it inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working exactly the correct way. You have a synchronized function which is fetching data in a background thread

```
infoRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: String]
    for item in postDict! {

        let theString = item.value["FirebaseString"]
        let theNumber = item.value["FirebaseInt"]                

        self.myDict[theNumber] = theString

        //First Print
        print(myDict)
    }
})
```

The code inside this closure is called after you received data from the remote data base. So if you have another `print(myDict)` right after this async call, it will get printed out first, which contains the original values. Then when the async call is finished and the code inside closure is excuted, the first `print(myDict)` is triggered then with the newly updated data

That being said, your new array is **not loaded with data until the call back to your closure**. From your code, it seems like you have a table view displaying data base on this array. So you have to wait until array gets the data and then reload table view. So you need to bring that code to the end of the closure. However, in swift, you cannot update UIElement directly from a back end thread, like this call back function. So after you get your array filled, you need to run table view reload code in main thread in this way

```
infoRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: String]
    for item in postDict! {

        let theString = item.value["FirebaseString"]
        let theNumber = item.value["FirebaseInt"]                

        self.myDict[theNumber] = theString

        //First Print
        print(myDict)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work, dictionary still shows up as [:] when printed anywhere other than `//First Print`

Comment: @BigJohnson as I mentioned, your second print is actually executed first, and then the first print. So we are expecting values only from the first print in your case. So what I am asking you to do is to move the data reload function under the first print, where you actually get the data from server call

Comment: Currently, the tableView does not hold anything. Once I get the dictionary working properly (not showing up as [:]), I will sort it and put it into an array, and then that array will show up in the tableView. So putting `tableView.reloadData()` inside of `dispatchQueue.main.async` does nothing at this point, because I am not able to set up the tableView until I get the dictionary working properly.

Comment: @BigJohnson Sure so you need to sort the dictionary and put it in another array. These operation should be done right under your first print inside the closure, you got that, right? You got the whole idea of the second print is useless, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the dictionary still has no values. For the tableView function numberOfRowsInSection, I have it do `return myDict.count` and there are no cells in the tableView. So for some reason the dictionary still has no values, even though my function `firebaseToDictionary()` provides it with values.

Comment: @BigJohnson No... You cannot count a dictionary. You can only count an array. So if you want to show data for dictionaries, you can have an array of them and then display the array on your table view. So you will be creating an empty array first, then on your database call, you create the dictionary and add it into the array. Then call reload data to load the array. Moving forward, dictionary is not a good practice to hold data. You can think of creating a class or struct to hold data instead of an array of dictionaries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148954/discussion-between-big-johnson-and-fangming-ning).

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems like `infoRef.observe()` is an asynchronous task and hence if you have a code right after that, it may get executed before the async task is executed. You can change your code as follows:

```
func firebaseToDictionary() {
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let infoRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("info")

    infoRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: String]
        for item in postDict! {

            let theString = item.value["FirebaseString"]
            let theNumber = item.value["FirebaseInt"]                

            self.myDict[theNumber] = theString

            //First Print
            print(myDict)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Anything you add after observe may get executed immediately without waiting for the observe part to be done. So make sure if you want to do something after that is finished, do it inside the block.

Comment: Doesnt fix it, dictionary still shows up as [:] when I print it elsewhere

Comment: Where are you printing? Are you printing it after first print is done? Why are you printing else where when your observe method is async block. You should wait for it to finish